# Common Lisp Loop Trouble

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have some trouble fully understanding CL's Loop macro.
This is my code for Project Euler Nr. 32:

```
(defun number-to-list (nr)
  (map 'list #'digit-char-p (prin1-to-string nr)))

(defun nine-digits-p (multiplicand multiplier )
  (= (length (equationlist multiplicand multiplier 
                                     (* multiplicand multiplier))) 9))

(defun equationlist (multiplicand multiplier product)
  (append (number-to-list multiplicand) (number-to-list multiplier)
      (number-to-list product)))

(defun pandigital (multiplicand multiplier)
  (equal (sort (equationlist multiplicand multiplier
                 (* multiplicand multiplier)) #'<)
     '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))

(defun pandigital-list ()
  (loop
       for i from 1 to 2000 collect
       (loop for j from 2 to 2000
       when (and (nine-digits-p i j) (pandigital i j)) collect (* i j))))


(defun euler-32 ()
  (reduce #'+ (reduce #'union (pandigital-list))))
```

Although this gives me the correct solution, my problem is with function "pandigital-list". Instead of collecting only the pandigital numbers, it returns a list filled with "NIL" and the few correct numbers.

How do I change this function to only return the numbers I am interested in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the inner `loop` returns `nil` whenever it does not collect anything else. (Remember: in Common Lisp everything has a value.)

One solution is to redefine `pandigital-list` like this:

```
(defun pandigital-list ()
   (loop for i from 1 to 2000
         for sublist = (loop for j from 2 to 2000
                             when (and (nine-digits-p i j)
                                       (pandigital i j))
                             collect (* i j))
             when sublist collect sublist))
```

Comment: This can be written slightly shorter:  `(loop for i from i to 2000 when (loop ...) collect it)`. `it` is a predefined variable which keeps the test result.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig. Thanks. I forgot the anaphoric possibilities of loop.